# How to design a unique CSS layout for HTML tag type="range" in all cross-browsers?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a FM player using pure CSS (no javascript) and tested the layout in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer (IE), and Edge browsers. Except Internet Explorer, the layout shows 99% accuracy as below.

[image: Chrome Layout]

The layout in IE is shown below,

[image: Internet Explorer Layout]

Is it possible to get 100% layout accuracy in all cross-browsers (others like Opera, Safari, etc.)?

The HTML code is used is below,

```html
<body>
    <div id="player">
        <audio id="musicPlayer" autoplay="autoplay">
            <source src="hls.mp3"/>
        </audio>
        <span id="playPause" onclick="playPause()"><img src="images/play.png" id="playMusic"/></span>
        <span id="time">00:00:00</span>
        <span id="volumeIcon"><img src="images/volume.png" id="volume"/></span>
        <input type="range" id="changeVolume" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="100"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

and CSS code is below,

```css
body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:helvetica;
}
#player {
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px outset darkgreen;
    box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px black, -5px 0 5px -5px black;
    background-image: linear-gradient(lightgreen, PaleGreen, lightgreen);
}
#time {
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
}
#playMusic, #pauseMusic {
    float:left;
    height:18px;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    cursor: default;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid limegreen;
    background-image: linear-gradient(lightgreen, PaleGreen, lightgreen);
    outline:none;
}
#playMusic:hover, #pauseMusic:hover {
    background:#94d362;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid ForestGreen;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    background: hsl(100, 100%, 85%);
}
input[type=range] {
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 120px;
    height:18px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 0;
    background: #228442;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: darkgreen;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #228442;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 0;
    background: #228442;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: darkgreen;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    animate: 0.2s;
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 3px 0;
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #228442;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #228442;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0;
    border: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: darkgreen;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #228442;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #228442;
}
#volume {
    margin-left:134px;
    width:20px;
}
```

The live test URL: https://biox.ml/fm

Comment: @Amessihel: IE 11.345.17134.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I finally found out that you should use the [flex positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) (supported by IE11).

- First, I edited the HTML design to use block elements (and to pack together the volume icon and range input to simplify the CSS styling).
- I set a `display:flex` for `div#player` to enable **`flex`** positioning.
- I put a `flex-grow:1` to `div#time` to let it fill the remaining space.
- I put to `div#volume` an `align-items:center` style to vertical align the `range` `input` and an `align-content:flex-end` to place the volume box to the right of the `div#player`.
- Finally, I set the top and the bottom paddings of the `range` `input` to 0 for IE11, and the height to 100% otherwise IE crops the thumb.
- Plus, some minor changes for the finishing and code cleaning.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: helvetica;
}


/* Beginning of the edited part */

#player {
  display: flex;
  height: 28px;
  width: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightgreen, PaleGreen, lightgreen);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px outset darkgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px black, -5px 0 5px -5px black;
}

div#playPause,
div#volume {
  height: 18px;
}

div#playPause {
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
}

div#volume {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

div#playPause img,
div#volume img {
  height: 100%;
}

div#time {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div#volume input[type=range] {
  width: 120px;
 height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  /* 0 paddings is important here */
  background-color: transparent;
}

div#volume input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* End of the edited part
  Below untouched specific-browser styling the "skin" of the range input
  "Untouched" except the prefix "div#volume"
*/

div#volume input[type=range] {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

div#volume input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0;
  background: #228442;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: darkgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

div#volume input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #228442;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0;
  background: #228442;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: darkgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 3px 0;
  color: transparent;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #228442;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #228442;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0;
}

div#volume input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: darkgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

div#volume input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #228442;
}

div#volume input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #228442;
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
  <audio id="musicPlayer" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="hls.mp3"/>
 </audio>
  <div id="playPause" onclick="playPause()">
    <img src="https://biox.ml/fm/images/play.png" id="playMusic" />
  </div>
  <div id="time">00:00:00</div>
  <div id="volume">
    <img src="https://biox.ml/fm/images/volume.png" id="playMusic" />
    <input type="range" id="changeVolume" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)" step="1" min="0" max="100" value="100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Little improvements.
Chrome Output: https://i.imgur.com/ZhHmzkN.jpg
IE Output: https://i.imgur.com/Cb3Ahc4.jpg

Comment: 100% accurate in IE and 99% accurate in Chrome, and other.

Comment: Wait... I will sent snapshots now.

Comment: The image of layout comparison is https://i.imgur.com/hoTKmC5.jpg
I'll host the full source code and will update the link soon.

Comment: Thank you very very  much. Your suggestion solved my problem. Now 99.9% accuracy. Only small variation in IE. I have attached the link https://i.imgur.com/jZXan8a.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183304/discussion-between-ak-se-and-amessihel).

Answer (score 0):

I think that changing the vertical align property in the CSS might help:

`#changeVolume{
  vertical-align: middle;
}`

**Update**

You could try doing this:

```
 #player{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

 #changeVolume{

display: inline-block;

}
```

I hope so that would work...

Comment: It displays worse than before. Comes out of the layout.

Comment: So it goes out in IE?

Comment: Yes. I have tested now in IE.

Comment: No improvement. Instead it goes to left corner.

Comment: Is it **vertically** in the position you wanted?

Comment: I want a unique layout, which is compatible in all browser as mentioned in https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdQLC.jpg